# How to reward player characters that take the time to research and read books, etc. about creatures or lore?

Tags: dnd-5e

For example, let's say a PC acquired a book about ghouls and took the time to thoroughly read through it. What are some ways to reward that player for taking the time in-game to do this?

Some things I've thought up myself (though I'm not sure if these would be 'balanced'):

- Giving the PC in question a +x amount of bonus to their attack when trying to hit that certain creature (or granting the PC permanent advantage when trying to hit it) because the PC has read about some of the creature's weak spots during his reasearch.
- Revealing 1 or more stats about the creature depending on the book and how much time they spend researching the topic. (By "revealing a stat" I don't necessarily mean giving the player knowledge of an actual stat, like its Intelligence modifier or something but rather saying something/hinting along the lines of "You've discovered that ghouls more than not tend to be driven by their hunger rather than their intelligence when it comes to making decisions.")
- Telling the PC about some of the creature's habits. Continuing the example of ghouls, this could be something like "Most sources seem to agree that ghouls rarely venture alone, on the contrary they tend to create groups or packs." or "Ghouls usually use their claws to paralyze their target before digging their fangs into it, assuring they can devour at their heart's content without the target struggling or escaping."

Other ideas, thoughts or comments are most certainly welcome.

Comment: I think this is an interesting question, but I think it may be off-topic for this site due to the open-ended nature of the question. A more on-topic question would be if you had some proposals you've already come up with for how you might reward this character that you put in your post, and we'd be able to provide feedback on whether those proposals are appropriate.

Comment: Another possibility is that your curiosity is best satisfied by more of a discussion than SE is really good at. In that case you may find [this list of forums we recommend](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5449/23970) useful. Included among those is Our Very Own [chat]; when you've got 20 reputation you'll be able to participate there and I hope you do--I'm sure plenty of people there have some ideas/experience incorporating players' "extracurricular" work into their games. Welcome to the site!

Comment: So your edit does make it a bit better, but it still is asking us to generate ideas/thoughts on this issue which this site does not handle well. I would highly recommend jumping into [chat] though and maybe people will have some ideas/answers for you (or even thoughts on how to improve the question)

Comment: Allright, I'll do that then. Just thought I'd gave it a shot here, primarily since I didn't know that that the time of posting. Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 4):

The best way to reward a player that makes his character do something in-character is to give them "Inspiration". Inspiration is a mechanical reward for playing the way the Dungeon Master appreciates.

I'll quote from the [Player's Basic Rules book](http://dnd.wizards.com/articles/features/basicrules?x=dnd/basicrules):

> ### Inspiration
>
> Inspiration is a rule the Dungeon Master can use to reward you for playing your character in a way that’s true to his or her personality traits, ideal, bond, and flaw. By using inspiration, you can draw on your personality trait of compassion for the downtrodden to give you an edge in negotiating with the Beggar Prince. Or inspiration can let you call on your bond to the defense of your home village to push past the effect of a spell that has been laid on you.
>
> ### Gaining Inspiration
>
> Your DM can choose to give you inspiration for a variety of reasons. Typically, DMs award it when you play out your personality traits, give in to the drawbacks presented by a flaw or bond, and otherwise portray your character in a compelling way. Your DM will tell you how you can earn inspiration in the game.
>   You either have inspiration or you don’t—you can’t stockpile multiple “inspirations” for later use.
>
> ### Using Inspiration
>
> If you have inspiration, you can expend it when you make an attack roll, saving throw, or ability check. Spending your inspiration gives you advantage on that roll.
>   Additionally, if you have inspiration, you can reward another player for good roleplaying, clever thinking, or simply doing something exciting in the game. When another player character does something that really contributes to the story in a fun and interesting way, you can give up your inspiration to give that character inspiration.

Answer (score 3):

## Encounters that turn on specialized knowledge

Write an encounter that only the character with specialized knowledge can do easily.  Some niche piece of information that allows them to recognize something particular about a ghoul being faced or a ghoul's den.

### Example

#### Foo, the sage, knows about an esoteric subspecies of ghoul

The character, Foo, has read extensively about ghouls.  He notices the telltale drag marks at entrance that resemble a poor attempt at sweeping and the relatively flat stone floor chosen for a lair.  Indicate that this is some audiophilic ghoul den and tell them that they're unusually sensitive to voices.

#### Encounter solution using the knowledge

Set up the encounter such that if they can use only hand signals and no vocalizations, they can retrieve or get past the challenge without combat.  The specialized knowledge is an alternative way to defeat the encounter.  The reward is whatever exp and treasure the encounter would yield.

Allow the player to further interrogate the character's knowledge by asking questions.  e.g.  The player could ask "Does Foo know if they respond to footsteps?", and the answer could be "Foo seems to recall that these ghouls are known to ignore noises that don't come out of a mouth."

Comment: As I understand it, it's not that the real-world player found an interesting book. It's that the _in-game_ PC found a book and studied it.

Comment: @mattdm I did not read it that way initially.  Thanks for pointing that out.